# Eager initializations of Java libs

Tags: java, constructor

I am using ExecutorService from Java concurrent libs, but I am not sure if I should initialize ExecutorService eagerly as follows.

```
public class Opts extends Runnable {
   //...
   private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
   //...
}
```

Normally I would not initialize 3rd party dependencies or my own class but in this case, it is from Java and guessing it's dependency is minimal. What should I prefer?

Usecase: Opts class is also Runnable and listens events. When an event comes, it executes it using ExecutorService.

Comment: It really depends on use case, without insights and approaches you have taken no one will be able to help you

Comment: updated  with usecase

Comment: in that case declare it constant

Comment: if Opts is not a singleton and you are creating pool for each Opts object - you must make sure to call `executor .shutdown()` when object is past its use

Comment: Make eager inits your default, and make all your fields final by default. Only deviate from that if you have good reasons to do so. Doing makes your code much more robust: it has less different "states" than can occur, making things immutable reduces code complexity dramatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prefer what you like.  It is up to you to make up your own mind.

But I would recommend that you keep it simple.  Use eager initialization unless there is a *good* reason to use lazy initialization.

(A good reason in this case might be that the thread pool is unlikely to needed, or that fast startup for your application is a critical requirement.)

---

> Normally I would not initialize 3rd party dependencies or my own class but in this case ...

You might want to review that.  I am not sure that a blanket preference is justified.  Especially one that may make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Can you elaborate the last part?

Comment: Which part needs elaborating?  It looks pretty clear to me.  Especially if you read it in the context of the earlier part of my answer.